# remove null values if the checkbox is not checked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
function modChkIdArr() {
    var modchkid = new Array();
    var i = 0;

    $("input[name='modChkId[]']").each(function() {

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            modchkid[i] = $(this).val();
        }
        i++;
    });

    $('#create_module').val(modchkid);
}

var moduleArr = $('#create_module').val().split(",");
alert(moduleArr);
```

When I check for multiple checkboxes (say 1st,3rd, 5th), it's returning 1,,3,,5

I want to remove the null values present in the array.

Comment: Look at the answer I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery, there are a lot of things you can do with it.

```
function modChkIdArr() {
    //Create array using .map function.
    var checkedValues = $("input[name='modChkId[]']:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $('#create_module').val(checkedValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `i++` inside the if condition

```
function modChkIdArr() {
  var modchkid = new Array();
  var i = 0;
  $("input[name='modChkId[]']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      modchkid[i] = $(this).val();
      i++;
  //--^------   
    }
  });
}
var moduleArr = $('#create_module').val().split(",");
alert(moduleArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the `i`, you are updating it irrespective of check-box is checked/un-checked.

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   modchkid[i] = $(this).val();
   i ++;//move here
}
//i++; //here
```

OR, you may also, try this:

```
if (this.checked) {
   modchkid[i ++] = this.value;
}
```

You could reduce your code, try `:checked` selector and `map()`:

```
function modChkIdArr() {
    var modchkid = $("input[name='modChkId[]']:checked").map(function() {
       return this.value; //get checkbox value
    }).get(); //get array
    $('#create_module').val(modchkid.join(',')); //csv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with prop

```
function modChkIdArr() {
  var modchkid = new Array();
  var i = 0;
  $("input[name='modChkId[]']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      modchkid[i] = $(this).val();
      i++;
  //--^------   
    }
  });
}
var moduleArr = $('#create_module').val().split(",");
alert(moduleArr);
```